ProjectIDX on Android Studio
Question:
how to setup android studio on project IDX(java language for logic).
Description:
ProjectIDX is a cloudbased IDE which was recently released by Google.Now beta version version is available.
link: https://idx.dev/
Need:complete set up on ProjectIDX for android studio. To develop an android app and the environment must be like a android studio with an emulator .
